# windows c# application for web browser control

Tags: c#, java, windows, webbrowser-control

I am looking a tutorial for develop a C# application for windows, which can give a extra functionality to the browser controls. i.e. input fields such as input box, text area.

When I using Google+, Facebook, and Twitter also my blog I use my native language. (Sinhala)
My native language has a complexity when is it come to using in computer. it has its own keyboard but it is really difficult to remember. In this case there are some tools to convert English characters in to its phonetic word in my language

i.e.

http://www.ucsc.cmb.ac.lk/ltrl/services/feconverter/t2.html

this above online tool help to convert English character in to is phonetic meaning in my language

i.e. Apal => ඇපල් (Apple)

This tool is developed by University of Colombo School Of Computing SriLanka. That English to Sinhala conversion control by JS.

My requirement is how this get in to C# application and running in particular pc, and when I open my web browser (Firefox, IE, Chrome, etc. ).

It should have run on system background and there should be a system tray icon to on/off it functions on browser (or Short cut key). And when it turn on.

I am wondering how I write a C# app for control Browser inputs and so on.

if you can show me a way to start or If I can have any suitable tutorial, guideline, or code sample, it will be great.

p.s. C# or Java is my prefer language

many thanks
Cheers
Umanda

Answer (score 1):

I would check out the [MSDN documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) for the Web Browser Control. It also provides a sample of the source code at the bottom of the page.

> It should have run on system background and there should be a system tray icon to on/off it functions on browser (or Short cut key). And when it turn on.

What you require is a Windows Service, that can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Absolutely, it is my pleasure! I imagine what you are trying to do is quite a feat and my answer might not exactly have been what you are looking for, but I hope it is a step in the right direction.